# deleting Rows in rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: jquery, richfaces, richdatatable

I have a `rich:extendedDataTable`. I have a `a4j:commandLink` for each row, on click of this the row should get deleted. The problem what I am facing is, if I go on deleting the first rows the (firstRow+1)second row's value is set in the backing bean and always the second row is getting deleted.

xhtml code is

```
<a4j:commandLink id="acceptbtn"
                            action="#    {archiveOrderBean.acceptOrder}"
                            styleClass="beforeSelect" title="#{mnOrdrMsgs.startitle}"
                            onclick="animateRow(this);" reRender="auftragListNew">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{archive}"
                                target="#{archiveOrderBean.currentOrder}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row}"
                                target="#{archiveOrderBean.currentRow}" />
                            <h:graphicImage value="/images/tick.png"
                                style="border:0;vertical-align: top;" />
                            <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="newclassification"
                                onsubmit="javascript:blockFullScreen('Loading...Please wait');"
                                oncomplete="javascript:myJQuery.unblockUI();" />
                        </a4j:commandLink>
```

I also tried rerendering the table but still the value in the UI is not in sync with the backing bean data. Does anybody have a solution to this.  I do not know if this is problem with richfaces 3.3.3 version. In addition to the action I also have the jquery code which flickers the row and removes the complete `<tr>`.

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery slide toggle removes the `<tr>` from the rich:extendedDataTable and when the deleteObject is done on the backing of `rich:extendedDataTable` it removes always the second row since the first tr is already removed by JQuery which is not rendered. I could manage to do this in 3 steps w.r.t `a4j:commandLink`

1. onClick attribute: RowFlicker JQuery
2. action attribute: Remove the object from the backingbean List and reRender Table
3. oncomplete attribute: RowRemove using JQuery